# How to use`xdg-open` or `gnome-open` in a virtual terminal.

Tags: command-line, virtual-terminal

If I run a command like `xdg-open document.pdf` or `gnome-open image.png` from a `gnome-terminal` window, the file opens the way I want it to.

But if I press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> (for instance) first and execute a similar command in a virtual terminal instead, I get multiple error messages. When I switch back to the graphical environment, the file has not been opened.

I assume this is all normal behavior. But is there a way to actually do what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work for most programs if you set the environment variable `DESKTOP` to `:0` so programs know where your X server is, and `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` to `0` (or some other value) as `xdg-open` uses that to guess that you are using GNOME.

For example:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=0
xdg-open document.pdf
```

Comment: It works! (With xdg-open only, and it's case sensitive.)

Comment: `evince document.pdf` also works! I'll see if I can set those environment values by default...

Comment: Putting those `export` statements in `~/bash_profile` seems to work, I hope it's safe!

Comment: Setting `$DISPLAY` in `~/.bash_profile` can have undesired side effects, like overwriting the value set by e.g. `ssh` for X forwarding. Some programs that work in text mode without `$DISPLAY` set will switch to GUI mode, which may or may not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read `man xdg-open`, which says, in part:

```
xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only.
```

The <kbd>CTRL-ALT-F1</kbd> session is NOT "a desktop session:". To see the difference in the environments do `env >env.desktop` in your desktop, `env >env.terminal` in your <kbd>CTRL-ALT-F1</kbd> session, then compare the files with `diff env.terminal env.desktop`

Comment: "The CTRL-ALT-F1 session is NOT "a desktop session:"." -- Understood. My question is whether  I can get around that, and how.  

"To see the difference in the environments do..." -- As a basic level user, the output of this means nothing to me.  If there are specific variable(s) that are relevant here, please do explain.